# Azure Blob Storage: 412 (The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.) BlobContainerClient

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, blobstorage

I am using BlobContainerClient to get files from AzureBlobStorage.

The process is to get the files in AzureBlobStorage then it will download it to a local file and delete it after.

But I am getting error when I deploy it, but locally works fine.

> 412 (The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not
> met.)

Below is my sample code.

```
    BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(azureBlobSettings.Connectionstring, azureBlobSettings.Containername);

    var blobList = container.GetBlobs();

    foreach (var blobItem in blobList)
    {
        if (blobItem.Name.Contains(".csv"))
        {
            LogInfo($"Downloading file {blobItem.Name} ...");

            var blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);

            var blobSplit = blob.Name.Split("/");
            var blobPath = blobSplit[0];
            var blobName = blobSplit[1];

            blob.DownloadTo($"{csvSettings.TargetPath}{blobName}");

            blob.DeleteIfExists();
        }
    }
```

Below is the detailed error:

```
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.Download(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable`1 timeout, String range, String leaseId, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentMD5, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentCRC64, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, Nullable`1 encryptionAlgorithm, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, String ifMatch, String ifNoneMatch, String ifTags,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartDownloadAsync(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, Int64 startOffset, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadStreamingInternal(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, IProgress`1 progressHandler, String operationName, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadStreaming(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, IProgress`1 progressHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.PartitionedDownloader.DownloadTo(Stream destination, BlobRequestConditions conditions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StagedDownloadAsync(Stream destination, BlobRequestConditions conditions, IProgress`1 progressHandler, StorageTransferOptions transferOptions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](Task`1 task)   
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadTo(String path, BlobRequestConditions conditions, StorageTransferOptions transferOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadTo(String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadTo(String path)
```

Comment: Please I badly need help.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi @Guarav Mantri. It's the blob.DownloadTo()

Comment: Please check if the blob is not leased.

Comment: what do you mean by blob is leased?

Comment: Please see this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob.

Comment: Hi @Guarav Mantri. The blob is not leased.

Comment: Hmm...can you check the `ErrorCode` in the exception? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.requestfailedexception?view=azure-dotnet#properties

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri. This is the error code.

Azure.RequestFailedException: The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
RequestId:94d38bcb-f01e-0066-30a9-dc102d000000
Time:2022-10-10T13:11:23.3547754Z
Status: 412 (The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.)
ErrorCode: ConditionNotMet

Comment: This is quite weird. I was expecting error code to match the ones mentioned here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes. I also tried to run your code locally and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyCuartero please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-conditional-headers-for-blob-service-operations